# Action economy with the Pathfinder Double-Chained Kama while its chain is extended

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, multiattack

The [Double-Chained Kama](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/kama-double-chained) says the following:

> The wielder can attack as if armed with a single kama in each hand or extend the chain to make a single reach attack. By swinging the rope, the wielder can whip the kama about to disarm or trip opponents. Furthermore, if one of the weapons is dropped, the wielder can retrieve as a free action by pulling on the chain.

Question 1: If your character has multiple attacks per round, can you make multiple attacks/trips with the extended chain?

Question 2: What action does it take to extend or retract the chain? A free action?

Question 3: While the chain is extended, can you use the kama that is up close to make an attack/trip(s) if you wanted to?

Comment: Welcome to RPG! Take the [tour]. Normally we look for just one question per post, but these are close enough in essence that I think it's OK.

Comment: I have to disagree with Fering's #1 answer...I believe it is simply saying/implying that you can make a single attack and not a double attack with the chain extended.
Now, if you have multiple attacks...you have multiple attacks.
Then...since it's a monk weapon, I would presume that you can make flurry of blows with it.
This doesn't seem unbalanced, it is powerful...but it requires being a monk after all and all the highly disciplined training that they go through.

Comment: You should probably post that comment on Fering's answer so they can address it directly.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to Question 1: Sadly no, the weapon description clearly states a single reach attack. This sounds like this feature of the weapon has been made into a standard attack much like vital shot.

Answer to Question 2: No action is mentioned, and as using the reach attack part of the weapon sounds like a standard action I would assume that letting it out or swinging it would be part of that action.

Answer to Question 3: I would have to answer no as the first line of the description is "The wielder can attack as if armed with a single kama in each hand **or** extend the chain to make a single reach attack." Please note how I bolded the word or. This means that you either have both in hand or are making the reach attack. However this seems foolish to me and I would ask your DM to allow you to make attacks. It is a free action to recover the 2nd weapon after all.

You should note that your Kama is a double weapon

> Double: You can use a double weapon to fight as if fighting with two weapons, but if you do, you incur all the normal attack penalties associated with fighting with two weapons, just as if you were using a one-handed weapon and a light weapon. You can choose to wield one end of a double weapon two-handed, but it cannot be used as a double weapon when wielded in this way—only one end of the weapon can be used in any given round.

Comment: First time user here...so getting the hang of this...posted above in the wrong spot, so reposting here.
I have to disagree with Fering's #1 answer...I believe it is simply saying/implying that you can make a single attack and not a double attack with the chain extended. Now, if you have multiple attacks...you have multiple attacks. Then...since it's a monk weapon, I would presume that you can make flurry of blows with it. This doesn't seem unbalanced, it is powerful...but it requires being a monk after all and all the highly disciplined training that they go through.

Comment: By the way.
Has anyone seen the mini series, Marco Polo and watch the character "Hundred Eyes" whip his chained weapon about?

Answer (score 1):

1: As I understand it the single attack part is there because it is no double weapon when extended. So a full attack is possible but not the TWF bonus attack(s).

2: Retrieving one kama is a free action so going from reach to double is a free action. It doesn't say what kind of action it is to go from double to reach.

3: Probably not. But as it seems to be a free action to go from reach to double, that would be an option if the attack you want to make happens during your turn.